# PowerShell remove offline machines from a list

Tags: powershell, loops, arraylist, foreach

I have a script which I want to do a `Test-Connection` on a list of machines and then remove the offline machines from the list. This is what I have:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Systems = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt

Foreach ($System in $Systems){
  if ($false -eq (Test-Connection -CN $System -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
    $Systems.Remove("$System")
  } 
}
$Systems
```

This fails with this error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. At
>   C:\temp\test.ps1:3 char:10 + Foreach ($System in $Systems){ + ~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a collection (`$Systems`) while there is an enumeration in progress on that same collection (or, to be precise, [you can't *continue* enumerating a collection after it's been modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.getenumerator#System_Collections_ArrayList_GetEnumerator)).  Instead of *removing offline* computers from an *existing* list, *add online* computers to a *new* list.

```bsh
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Systems = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$OnlineSystems = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList'

Foreach ($System in $Systems){
  if ($true -eq (Test-Connection -CN $System -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
    $OnlineSystems.Add("$System")
  } 
}
$OnlineSystems
```

Note that you don't need to compare an expression to a boolean when it already evaluates to a boolean, and you don't need to use string interpolation on a variable that is already a `[String]`, so you can simplify the body of the `Foreach` loop to...

```bsh
if (Test-Connection -CN $System -Count 1 -Quiet) {
    $OnlineSystems.Add($System)
}
```

Even more concise code that avoids the enumeration conflict entirely would be to use the pipeline and [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)...

```bsh
[String[]] $OnlineSystems = @($Systems | Where-Object { Test-Connection -CN $_ -Count 1 -Quiet })
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because modifying a collection while iterating it is not allowed. The underlying reasons are a bit complex, but well [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26864676/503046) in other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3875401/503046).

To change a collection, `foreach` won't do but a `for` loop does. ArrayList's `RemoveAt()` will remove elements by index. Like so,

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $Systems.Count;  ++$i) {
    if( -not (Test-Connection -CN $systems[$i] -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        $systems.RemoveAt($i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all! So many options here and I have a solution now. I have also now learnt that modifying a collection while iterating it is not allowed!