# C# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)

HI there,

I am create an project estimation program and am getting the following error: C# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

It is related to using this: 
I initally declare the diciontary globally with this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> rankings = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

The Next Method  containing this dictionary does the following:

```
private void getFirstEstimation()
{
    List<int> array = new List<int>();

    string strConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    MySqlDataReader reader;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT idprojects FROM `test`.`projects` WHERE application_layers = " + applicationTiers;
    connection.Open();

    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        array.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["idprojects"].ToString()));
    }
    foreach (int i in array)
    {
        rankings[i] = 15;
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

I call it for a second time here:

```
private void getSecondEstimation()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> sqltext = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    Dictionary<int, int> valueForSql = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    Dictionary<int, int> weightings = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    sqltext.Add(1, "project_type");
    valueForSql.Add(1, projectType);
    weightings.Add(1, 10);
    sqltext.Add(2, "application_domain");
    valueForSql.Add(2, applicationDomain);
    weightings.Add(2, 8);
    sqltext.Add(3, "organisation_size");
    valueForSql.Add(3, organizationSize);
    weightings.Add(3, 8);
    sqltext.Add(4, "no_of_locations");
    valueForSql.Add(4, noOfLocations);
    weightings.Add(4, 7);
    sqltext.Add(5, "development_process");
    valueForSql.Add(5, developmentProcess);
    weightings.Add(5, 6);
    sqltext.Add(6, "rules_engine");
    valueForSql.Add(6, rulesEngine);
    weightings.Add(6, 5);
    sqltext.Add(7, "middleware");
    valueForSql.Add(7, middleware);
    weightings.Add(7, 4);
    sqltext.Add(8, "location_of_development");
    valueForSql.Add(8, locationOfDevelopment);
    weightings.Add(8, 3);
    sqltext.Add(9, "programming_language");
    valueForSql.Add(9, programmingLanguage);
    weightings.Add(9, 3);
    sqltext.Add(10, "development_environment");
    valueForSql.Add(10, developmentEnvironment);
    weightings.Add(10, 3);
    sqltext.Add(11, "backend");
    valueForSql.Add(11, backend);
    weightings.Add(11, 3);
    sqltext.Add(12, "webserver");
    valueForSql.Add(12, webServer);
    weightings.Add(12, 3);

    List<int> array = new List<int>();

    string strConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT idprojects FROM `test`.`projects` WHERE " + sqltext[i] + " = " + valueForSql[i];
        connection.Open();
        //int testInt;
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            array.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["idprojects"].ToString()));
        }
        foreach (int a in array)
        {
            if (!rankings.ContainsKey(a))
            {
                rankings[a] = 0;
            }
            rankings[a] = rankings[a] + weightings[i];
        }
        connection.Close();
    }       
}
```

The problem arises at this area of the code:

```
private void getThirdEstimation()
{
    ArrayList tempModuleHolder;

    string strConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    MySqlDataReader reader;
    int similarModules;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in rankings)
    {
        similarModules = 0;
        tempModuleHolder = new ArrayList();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT id_modules FROM `test`.`modules_in_project` WHERE id_project = " + kvp.Key;
        connection.Open();

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            tempModuleHolder.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["id_modules"].ToString()));
        }

        foreach (int i in tempModuleHolder)
        {
            if(modules.Contains(i))
            {
                similarModules++;
            }
        }
        if((double)(similarModules/modules.Count)>0.6)
        {
            //kvp.Value = kvp.Value + 4;
            rankings[kvp.Key] = rankings[kvp.Key] + 4;
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Any help with where the problem lies will be much appreciated

Comment: btw, off the topic, your MySqlConnection and MySqlDataReader class does not implement IDisposable to Dispose() method, so that you can use using block around connection and reader?

Comment: @ydobonmai: `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlDataReader` probably refer to `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` classes for working with MySQL databases. Therefore, they do implement `IDisposable` and their use should be wrapped in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Any collection that you iterate over with foreach may not be modified during iteration.

So while you're running a foreach over rankings, you cannot modify its elements, add new ones or delete any.

Comment: You can however loop through a copy of the collection. For instance `Collection.ToArray()` at the loop instanciation. This will let you modify your actual collection in the loop while not altering the "Copy" of the Collection. Source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute

Comment: +1 Don: ToArray() fixes it. +1 to @Roy as well.

Comment: I wonder why this bug wasn't fixed yet.

Answer (score 25):

The error tells you EXACTLY what the problem is (and running in the debugger or reading the stack trace will tell you exactly where the problem is):

> C# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Your problem is the loop

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in rankings) {
    //
}
```

wherein you modify the collection `rankings`. In particular, the offensive line is

```
rankings[kvp.Key] = rankings[kvp.Key] + 4;
```

Before you enter the loop, add the following line:

```
var listOfRankingsToModify = new List<int>();
```

Replace the offending line with

```
listOfRankingsToModify.Add(kvp.Key);
```

and after you exit the loop

```
foreach(var key in listOfRankingsToModify) {
    rankings[key] = rankings[key] + 4;
}
```

That is, record what changes you need to make, and make them without iterating over the collection that you need to modify.

Answer (score 14):

As others have pointed out, you are modifying a collection that you are iterating over and that's what's causing the error.  The offending code is below:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in rankings)
{
    .....

    if((double)(similarModules/modules.Count)>0.6)
    {
        rankings[kvp.Key] = rankings[kvp.Key] + 4;  // <--- This line is the problem
    }
    .....
```

What may not be obvious from the code above is where the `Enumerator` comes from.  In a blog post from a [few years back about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) Eric Lippert provides an example of what a `foreach` loop gets expanded to by the compiler.  The generated code will look something like:

```
{
    IEnumerator<int> e = ((IEnumerable<int>)values).GetEnumerator(); // <-- This
                                                       // is where the Enumerator
                                                       // comes from.
    try
    { 
        int m; // OUTSIDE THE ACTUAL LOOP in C# 4 and before, inside the loop in 5
        while(e.MoveNext())
        {
            // loop code goes here
        }
    }
    finally
    { 
      if (e != null) ((IDisposable)e).Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you look up the MSDN documentation for [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) (which is what `GetEnumerator()` returns) you will see:

> Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, **but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.**

Which brings us back to what the error message states and the other answers re-state, you're modifying the underlying collection.

Comment: Potential readers: Please ignore the downvote, it was done in a fit of nerdrage.  ROMAN: if you edit this answer I'll remove the downvote, its past the time limit and won't let me do it.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect the error is caused by this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in rankings)
```

rankings is a dictionary, which is IEnumerable. By using it in a foreach loop, you're specifying that you want each KeyValuePair from the dictionary in a deferred manner. That is, the next KeyValuePair is not returned until your loop iterates again.

But you're modifying the dictionary inside your loop:

```
rankings[kvp.Key] = rankings[kvp.Key] + 4;
```

which isn't allowed...so you get the exception.

You could simply do this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in rankings.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is where you are executing:

```
rankings[kvp.Key] = rankings[kvp.Key] + 4;
```

You cannot modify the collection you are iterating through in a foreach loop.  A foreach loop requires the loop to be immutable during iteration.

Instead, use a standard 'for' loop or create a new loop that is a copy and iterate through that while updating your original.