# Does List<T> Sort modify the collection?

Tags: c#, .net

does List Sort modify the collection?

I think it must as I get a "System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." exception on another thread.

In my multi-threaded app all threads I thought were just reading the collection BUT one thread does a sort.

Thanks

Comment: Sorting a collection shouldn't modify the individual elements, but it will obviously modify the *collection*.

Comment: But will it cause a modified collection exception?

Comment: look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute

Comment: @CodingQuant: Yes, because it's modifying the collection.

Comment: @CodingQuant If an Iterator is going through a collection and it gets modified, it will throw a "modified collection" exception. This makes sense doesn't it? If you've got a collection of items and you're looking through them one-by-one, it's going to be quite confusing if someone else comes along and re-orders them!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) is in-place, if that's what you mean, and it will certainly invalidate any iterators.

If you want to see a sorted "view" of the collection, you can use LINQ's [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) operator, which doesn't modify the existing collection but returns a sequence which contains the elements from the original collection, but in the given order.

So for example, instead of:

```
// I want to print out the list of names, sorted...
names.Sort();
foreach (string name in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

You could use:

```
foreach (string name in names.OrderBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Another alternative is just to sort it once when you first populate the list, before anything starts iterating over it - that's the *only* modification required, and if the sort order won't change (e.g. due to modifications to the objects referred to in the list) then it would make sense to just do it once.

Comment: A bit of additional info, what I've found out:
`Sort()` invalidates the iterator, but `Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)` does not. At least calling `Sort((a,b) => a.CompareTo(b))` on a list of integers doesn't throw the InvalidOperationException when iterating through this list from another thread.

Comment: @BalintPogatsa: Even if it happens not to in some situations, I would *definitely* not rely on that unless it's documented somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the `List<T>.Sort` method does indeed sort the collection in place and hence modifies the collection.  If you want instead to get a new collection which is sorted that doesn't modify the original then use the `OrderBy` extension method.

```
List<int> theList = ...;
theList.Sort();  // In place mutating sort. Has a void return
List<int> sorted = theList
  .OrderBy(Comparer<int>.Default)
  .ToList();
```