# Collection was modified while enumeration

Tags: c#, list, thread-safety, action

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)

I have a generic List where I execute some actions while enumerating.

```
foreach(Action<string> action in actionList) 
{
    if(action != null) {
        action(mystring);
    }
}
```

Now I get this exception:

```
InvalidOperationException:
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute
```

How can this be solved, I am nailed tight to .NET 3.5 :/

Comment: Check out “Related” column on the right side of the page, there is a huge number of same question answered.

Answer (score 6):

Well presumably one of the actions modifies `actionList`, invalidating the iterator. The simplest way to avoid the error is to take a copy of the list first, e.g.

```
foreach(Action<string> action in actionList.ToList()) 
{
    if(action != null) {
        action(mystring);                               
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
foreach (var action in actionList.Where(action => action != null).ToList())
{
    action(mystring);
}
```

Comment: +1. answer in less than 1min :)

Comment: I tried your first code snippet which throws a NullRefException :(

Comment: @Pascal: It shouldn't... where did it throw an exception? I assume `actionList` itself is non-null? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help...

Comment: The exception I get in a third party assembly.

Comment: @Pascal: Then presumably it's a bug somewhere in that, or in how you're using it... but there's no way of me fixing that in the code you're giving here. That's a completely separate problem to the one you've given in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You modified the actionList during the iteration on it. It could be a second thread which is not synchronized with a current loop or the action method which make the modification or another iteration. So the solution could be:

```
var tmp = new List<Action<string> >(actionList);
foreach(Action<string> action in tmp) 
{
    if(action != null) {
      action(mystring);                               
    }
}
```

But it will work only in case of action's modification in case of a parallel thread you should synchronize the list.

Comment: same as Skeets answer => NullRefException

Comment: I know I wrote it while Skeets posted his answer, so should I delete it? Also there is mentioned that the problem could come in the multithreaded environment.