# Exception while Refresh-ing Items of ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, listbox

I have a WFP application with a `ListBox` and a `Button`:

```
<Window x:Class="UITester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <ListBox Name="list"></ListBox>
        <Button Click="ButtonSelect_OnClick">Select Stuff</Button>
</Window>
```

In the code behind I have this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> _selected = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        list.ItemsSource = _selected.Values;
    }

    private void ButtonSelect_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _selected.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            _selected.Add(i, i);                
        }

        list.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

If I run the application without a debugger attached everything seems all right - I click the button and the number 0 to 3 appear in the list.

However, if I run this with a debugger attached I see that when calling the line `list.Items.Refresh();` there's an exception thrown:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

As far as I know, this exception is thrown when trying to change a collection while enumerating it. But I'm pretty sure this isn't the case. Everything here happens in the UI thread. First I add elements to the dictionary and only once that's done, I refresh the items in the list box. It seems to me that nothing is changed and in fact, nothing is enumerated.
I suppose that the `Refresh` method enumerates the dictionary's values, but they have already been updated and are not changed during this enumeration.

I know this is not the best way to update a `ListBox`, but it's part of a much larger and older code, and I just want to understand what's wrong here.

**UPDATE**

When I change `_selected` to be `List<int>` and set `list.ItemsSource = _selected;` then there's no exception and no warnings in the output window. But when I set `_selected` to be 'HashSet` then the problems come back.

Comment: Did you try porting this code into a test app and see if you get the same results?

Comment: @Dina, i have checked your code snippet in my VS2012. It is working fine and the bug you raised was not reproducible. Can you try this snippet in a test application and see the issue remain exist. If yes please make the critical section thread safe using c# lock technique.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error...can you explain better what you are doing?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute
Though this really seems weird behaviour.

Comment: @FabianBigler But, there's no foreach in sight.

Comment: @LeeLouviere Yes, I agree, and I couldn't reproduce it either. Seems like a ghost who's playing tricks. ;)

Comment: The code I attached was in fact my entire test repro. I'm running Windows 7 x64, VS 2012 update 2 and the project is .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Dina That may be all the code related to these fields/data, but did you try isolating the code? Is that all the code in your project?
There's nothing there to cause your issue and the people who've copied that code into a new project don't have that issue.

Comment: @LeeLouviere This is the entire code. There's nothing else. Like I wrote in my non-complete answer below, the exception comes from deep within WPF and is also caught there. I can see it only when I choose to break when exception are thrown or in the debugging output window. The code works perfectly and the UI is updated whenever needed. However, I don't understand the internals of this and why this happens. I don't understand why List is special and doesn't cause the exception. I'm curious about what's under the hood...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, since I still don't understand why this happens and what's going on under the hood, but I have convinced myself that I shouldn't be worried about this. The exception occurres deep inside the WPF framework and is probably caught somewhere there. I can only see there's an exception when running with a debugger by looking at the output window:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

And only if I choose to break when the exception is thrown then the debugger indeed breaks. There are no unhandled exceptions.

So while the real reason for this is still a mystery, it would seem that the problem is not in my code...

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to maintain your own list separate from the `Dictionary` and copy values over when the `Dictionary` changes. I'd advise using an `ObservableCollection`, so you don't have to do a refresh call.

I swear I still have my code for an `ObservableDictionary` somewhere.