# Remove selected items from Listbox (ObservableCollection)

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I am trying to remove selected items in a ListBox which is bound to ObservableCollection.

```
var selectedFiles = MyList.SelectedItems;
foreach (cListEntry item in selectedFiles)
{
   _myList.Remove(item);
}
```

> "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute

Comment: Specially, read this comment.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute#comment13168776_604843

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **can't modify the collection while enumerating it** as evident from the exception itself.

*Explanation:*

When you remove item from ObservableCollection, *MyList.SelectedItems* gets update since ObservableCollecton implement *INotifyCollectionChanged*.
Now, selectedFiles is pointing to same reference which results in modifying it.

*Solution*

Instead create a new list and enumerate over that so that any change in ObservableCollection doesn't reflect back to list which you are enumerating. This will work:

```
var selectedFiles = MyList.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToList();
foreach (cListEntry item in selectedFiles)
{
   _myList.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the solution. I was not aware of that. This also seems to work MyList.SelectedItems.Count != 0){_myList.Remove((cListEntry)MyList.SelectedItems[0]);}

Comment: Yeah in case you want to remove only single item, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when trying to modify an `ObservableCollection<T>` that is bound to a ListBox, for example.  This is how you deal with that:

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> itemsToRemove = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

foreach (Employee item in lsbxNames.SelectedItems)
{
    itemsToRemove.Add(item);
}
foreach (Employee item in itemsToRemove)
{
    ((ObservableCollection<Employee>)lsbxNames.ItemsSource).Remove(item);
}
```

1. Create a new `ObservableCollection<T>` called `itemsToRemove`, with the same `T` as your collection you are trying to modify.
2. Iterate through your nodes of SelectedItems in your ListBox.  Add them to `itemsToRemove`.
3. Iterate through `itemsToRemove`.  Cast the ListBox ItemsSource to an `ObservableCollection<T>` and remove the matches in `itemsToRemove` from it.

Reference:  http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/managing-data/deleting-entry

So this would mean you should be able to do this:

```
ObservableCollection<cListEntry> itemsToRemove = new ObservableCollection<cListEntry>();

foreach (cListEntry item in MyList.SelectedItems)
{
    itemsToRemove.Add(item);
}
foreach (cListEntry item in itemsToRemove)
{
    ((ObservableCollection<cListEntry>)MyList.ItemsSource).Remove(item);
}
```

I'm not sure what `_myList` is, but you don't need to modify it.  Just go directly to the ListBox.