# foreach loop item removal from an enumerated collection

Tags: c#, foreach, enumeration

I can't figure out why this works:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1 };

foreach (var item in list.ToList())
{
    if (item == 1)
    {
        list.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

...and this doesn't:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1 };

foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (item == 1)
    {
        list.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

If you run the second snippet, it'll give you the following error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Per documentation, the enumeration only remains valid if it's unchanged.  What I don't get is how I'm able to get around it with the first code snippet?  Could someone break it down for me?

Comment: In the first example you are enumerating a 'copy' of the list and removing items from the original list.  In the second, your are enumerating the original list and trying to remove items from the original

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh my... do I feel silly.  You're absolutely right.

Comment: Side note: If you've searched for the "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." you'd immediately find [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute) that shows exactly your code as workaround.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've seen several of them, but didn't see that one.  The ones I saw didn't answer my question. My search parameters were a bit different, so that could be the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `.ToList()` isn't a *casting* operation, it makes a *copy* of your original list.

So you are then **iterating** over the *copy* and **modifying** the *original*.

Comment: You're right, I can't believe I didn't realize that.  All the time I had myself thinking, for some reason, that I'm casting and assigning.  What a silly mistake to make.

Answer (score 4):

Because in the first code snippet you are not iterating over your list, you are iterating over the *copy* of your list.

So removing an item from *original* list doesn't cause any exception because it is different from the collection that is being enumerated.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.  It's like not seeing the glasses on one's head.