# Removing IP from IIS Site Binding

Tags: c#, iis

Guys I am trying to remove a specific IP from IIS site bindings through C# (Microsoft Web Administration).

Basically what I want to do is, is to check all site's binding in IIS and if any binding IP matches user-provided IP, it should remove it and if the particular site doesn't have any other bindings with different IP then it should stop the site.

However, I can't seem to remove the IP in a loop as I am getting ***"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."*** error.

This is my code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();

    foreach (Site s in mgr.Sites)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Site {0}", s.Name);

        foreach (Application app in s.Applications)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tApplication: {0}", app.Path);

            foreach (VirtualDirectory virtDir in app.VirtualDirectories)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tVirtual Dir: {0}", virtDir.Path);
            }
        }

        BindingCollection bindingCollection = s.Bindings;
        foreach (Binding b in  bindingCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Bindings: {0}",b.EndPoint);
            if (b.EndPoint != null)
            {
                //Hard Coded IP for testing purpose
                if (b.EndPoint.ToString() == "1.1.1.1:86")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Removing this ip : {0}",b.EndPoint.ToString());
                    bindingCollection.Remove(b);
                }
            }
        }
      mgr.CommitChanges();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What should I do to remove the binding ? I need to remove it in a loop because a site may have more than 1 binding which uses the same IP.

Comment: create a copy of the collection first.

Comment: How? I can't seem to create an object of `BindingCollection` neither assign null to `BindingCollection` and then adding the binding to it works as I get "object not set to an instance of an object" error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enumerator is versioned for most collections that are part of the BCL, meaning that you cannot modify a collection while you are looping over it. You can copy the collection like so:

```
var bindingCollection = new List<Binding>(s.Bindings);
```

So now your loop looks like this:

```
var bindings = s.Bindings;
var bindingCollection = new List<Binding>(bindings);
foreach (Binding b in bindingCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n Bindings: {0}", b.EndPoint);
    if (b.EndPoint != null)
    {
        //Hard Coded IP for testing purpose
        if (b.EndPoint.ToString() == "1.1.1.1:86")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Removing this ip : {0}", b.EndPoint.ToString());
            bindings.Remove(b);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this does not actually remove the binding like you expect it to. You need to call `b.Delete()` to actually delete the binding. When you use `Remove`, all you are doing is removing it from the collection that was built from existing bindings. So add `b.Delete()` before you remove it from the collection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried what you suggested above and the iteration issue is gone however the binding is still there and doesn't seem to be deleted. I tried `b.Delete()` too but still I can see the bindings in IIS. Why is that?

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer I believe you need to call `mgr.CommitChanges();` after you are done removing all your bindings.