# Collection was modified, enumeration may not continue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, collections

I have a below code

```
public bool Notify(bool filterStatus)
{
   foreach (IFilterStatusListener listener in listeners)
   {
      listener.Update(filterStatus);
   }
   return true;
}
```

Method `Update` recursively calls `Notify` for Children

```
public void Update(bool status)
{
   this.isFilteredFixed = false;
   this.Notify(status);
   this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsFiltered");
}
```

When I run this code, I get below error
[image]

**What should I do ?**

Comment: You try to update your collection while you iterating it. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute

Comment: What is `listeners` here ?

Comment: Objects of Custom type which implement `IFilterStatusListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` expects that collection stays unchanged. You may try a normal `for` loop instead.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

> The **foreach** statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.  If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a **for** loop.

Answer (score 3):

When you iterate a collection with a foreach statement you can't change the collection you're iterating on, because the iterator gets lost on which position it actually is.

There are several solutions to this:

- You iterate with a for loop
- You create a copy of the collection you're iterating on and work on that.