# Error when deleting an item from collection

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove an element from Collection but ended up with error

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

**What i am trying to achieve?**

Check Student list count in Report collection.

If count is == 1
Than check null or empty for Student properties

If all true than delete Student from Report collection..

Here is my code

```
public void Create(StudentReport report)
{

    ICollection<StudentReportDetails> student= report.Students;
    if (student.Count == 1) 

    {
        foreach (StudentReportDetails Studetails in student)
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Studetails.StudentNumber)&& String.IsNullOrEmpty(Studetails.Description) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Studetails.Summary))
            {
                report.Students.Remove(Studetails);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it tagged both C# and C ?!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute

Comment: use `for` loop instead of `foreach`

Comment: As it says, you can't delete a collection item in an enumerator based loop. And we can understand why, in the current item is the way to the following. But you delete the current item, so, no following.

Comment: @ Garg Ankit why so harsh.. error is human nature. thanks for the edit.

Comment: @ Soner Gönül, thanks , your link solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can't modify a collection. Foreach loop makes the collection as readonly.

Comment: thanks for the info. i wasnt aware about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify it change `foreach` to `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < student.Count; i++)
{ 

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Studetails.StudentNumber)&& String.IsNullOrEmpty(Studetails.Description) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Studetails.Summary))
        {
            report.Students.Remove(Studetails);
        }

    }
```