# How use LINQ to remove maximum items in a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to remove items with the maximum value in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. I use `Where` to query the maximum value's key, and use`foreach` to remove it. But it throw a `System.InvalidOperationException` in `foreach` statement, the message is `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` But I don't think I have modified the collection at all in `foreach`!

Here is an example:

```
        Dictionary<char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        dic['a'] = 5;
        dic['b'] = 10;

        var maxVal = dic.Values.Max();
        var maxs = dic.Where(kv => kv.Value == maxVal);

        foreach(var entry in maxs)//the exception is thrown here
        {
            dic.Remove(entry.Key);//I don't modify maxs at all! I just remove items in dic!
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you're confused by how `Where()` works. Materialize the collection first by calling `Where(...).ToList()`. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute).

Comment: He didn't realise he was editing `dic` when he was editing `maxs`. The linked-to solution fixes this because the use of `dic.Where(...).ToList()` would make `maxs` a new list and thus he can iterate `maxs` while removing items from `dic`.