# Add to values to dictionary from Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, dictionary

I have a projest has Database And Store Variables.I want to store all values and columns in database and access again , but when i try to access im giving only last value in database.How can i fix this ?

```
public class Variables
{
    public static readonly List<Dictionary<string, string>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    public static Dictionary<string, string> column;
    public static String Name = null;
    public static String Surname = null;
    public static String Gsm = null;
    public static String QRCodeID = null;
    public static String Email = null;
    public static String indirimOrani = null;

}

public class SelectSave()
{
    var cmdSelectSave = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText =
            "SELECT Name,Surname,Gsm,QRCodeID,Email,indirimOrani FROM elmacustomers WHERE OnayID=1",
        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
        Connection = sqlConElmaCafePlus
    };

    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    reader = cmdSelectSave.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Variables.column = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["Name"] = reader["Name"].ToString(),
            ["Surname"] = reader["Surname"].ToString(),
            ["Gsm"] = reader["Gsm"].ToString(),
            ["QRCodeID"] = reader["QRCodeID"].ToString(),
            ["Email"] = reader["Email"].ToString(),
            ["indirimOrani"] = reader["indirimOrani"].ToString()
        };
        Variables.rows.Add(Variables.column);
    }
}

public void DataReceive()
{
    foreach (Dictionary<string, string> column in Variables.rows)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Variables.column["Name"]);//That's giving only last Name value in database. I want to scan all names in database.
    }
}
```

Comment: can you confirm more than one rows are being returned from database? I'm skeptical about this condition: `WHERE OnayID=1`

Comment: When You debug this and but a break point at the end of SelectSave, does Variables.rows have more columns than one?

Comment: Yes , when i insert a breakpoint every value stored in Variables.rows but how can i access this discrete? Photo Here : http://i.hizliresim.com/mErk4y.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `DataReceive()` function, while iterating over the rows use some different name for the iterator like `datarow` and then use this:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> column in Variables.rows.ToList())
{
    MessageBox.Show(column["Name"]);
}
```

Comment: ERROR : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: When are you getting this error? By making this change?

Comment: No all time . I changed like you nothing change

Comment: But you said you are getting the last as value and you are getting error also?

Comment: Yes after the click message box ok button , im giving error

Comment: Thats because of ToList().. Refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121055/discussion-between-richa-garg-and-ozan-manav).