# What collection is being modified? Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to serialize and object with this line:

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj, Formatting.Indented,
       new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
             ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });
```

myObj is rather a large object with many lists and properties.

My understanding is this error occurs when you are trying to iterate though an obj that has since been modified.

My question - is how can I figure out which collection is being modified?  Any special command I can run in immediate window to tell me which I should focus on?

Thank you,
B

Comment: Same here, we also can not figure out anything without seeing the class which you are trying to serialize and how are you populating it.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] so we can see the code in question.

Comment: What is the `StackTrace` of the exception being thrown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the stack trace in the exception being thrown you can identify the line where the error is. The collection around that line is the one that was modified.