# ForEach extension method not being called with Dictionary

Tags: c#

I've got a `Dictionary` that contains a `ValueTuple`:

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<RELAY, (byte RelayNumber, bool IsClosed)> s_relays = new Dictionary<RELAY, (byte RelayNumber, bool IsClosed)>
    {
        { RELAY.OUTPUT1, (4, false) },
        { RELAY.OUTPUT2, (9, false) },
        { RELAY.OUTPUT3, (11, false) },
    };
```

Later in my code I set `IsClosed` to true for one or more relays. I wrote a `ForEach` extension method for the `Dictionary`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
    {
        Debug.Assert(enumeration != null, $"Argument {nameof(enumeration)} cannot be null!");
        Debug.Assert(action != null, $"Argument {nameof(action)} cannot be null!");

        foreach (T item in enumeration)
        {
            action(item);
            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

I want to call a method for each relay that is closed. For example, writing to `Console.WriteLine`:

```
Relays.Where(x => x.Value.IsClosed).ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key));
```

But this does not work. However, if I include `ToList()` the code below *does* work:

```
Relays.Where(x => x.Value.IsClosed).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key));
```

What am I missing?

(I do realize that the `ForEach` extension method being called is different between these two examples with the first one [mine] never being called.)

Comment: have you try `Relays.Where(x => x.Value.IsClosed).ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key)).ToList()`? I think your extension method not called, because you do not enumerate your enumeration

Comment: `However, if I include ToList() the code below does work:` It works because when you do that you aren't calling your method. You are calling a completely different method - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, unlike the `List<T>.ForEach()` implementation that iterates a collection, by using the `yield return` pattern, your `.ForEach` implementation is actually a deferred execution "filter" that will not be executed until the query is fully resolved.

In that sense it is extremely similar to the `.Where()` method except that instead of reducing the query set, it is performing a side-effect operation on it as the query is resolved.  Neither will actually be executed until the enumeration is enumerated.

Adding `.ToList()` to the end of your query will execute your method as expected and resolve the query.

Alternatively, if you simply want a convenient way to iterate and perform an action on a collection, you could remove the `yield return` and simply iterate the collection and return it at the end:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    Debug.Assert(enumeration != null, $"Argument {nameof(enumeration)} cannot be null!");
    Debug.Assert(action != null, $"Argument {nameof(action)} cannot be null!");

    foreach (T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
    }

    return enumeration;
}
```

However, the risk there is that you could potentially enumerate twice.

---

It is also worth noting that your second example

```
Relays.Where(x => x.Value.IsClosed).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key));
```

does not actually invoke your extension method.  Rather, it invokes the `List<T>.ForEach()` method.

Comment: In that case, is there any advantage to writing my own extension method since I still need to call `ToList()`?

Comment: You can iterate your enumeration in this extension method `var collection = enumeration.ToList(); foreach (T item in collection) action(item); return collection;`

Comment: @DiskCrasher I believe you don't need to return a IEnumerable<T> from you ForEach() extension method. I don't have a computer with Visual Studio to try this out atm but I think making the method return something else (maybe an int counter showing how many object got iterated) could make it work as you intend without the ToList().

Comment: @DiskCrasher I've updated my answer to help add some additional clarity.

Comment: @Lucas while that is true if the implementation is an extension method, that isn't true if the method implements `yield return`, as I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Removing the `yield return` fixes this issue but results in an `InvalidOperationException` stating 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.' I may just stick to using `ToList()` since that resolves the issue.

Comment: @DiskCrasher I can't reproduce that issue.  For me the query executes correctly.  Do you have an expanded snippet that causes that problem?

Comment: @DavidL I do not. I believe it's the same issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute).

Comment: @DiskCrasher this is is most likely an example of the multiple enumerations possibility that I mentioned.  In your case, `.ToList()` at the end is probably the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a query and it will only be executed "lazily" when needed. Let's make things simple so we can see what happens:

```
private static readonly List<int> nums = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

public static IEnumerable<int> MyEach(this IEnumerable<int> enumeration, Action<int> action)
{ 
    foreach (var item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

This is just a query, so nothing will execute yet:

```
var query = nums.Where(x => x == 1).MyEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

But as soon as you do this:

```
query.ToList();
```

It will execute `MyEach` extension method.

You have to be careful because it depends when it gets executed. For example, try this and you will see the number 1 printed to the console 3 times:

```
var query = nums.Where(x => x == 1).MyEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
nums.Add(1);
nums.Add(1);
query.ToList();
```

However, if you removed the `yield`, then it will execute right away:

```
public static void MyEach(this IEnumerable<int> enumeration, Action<int> action)
{ 
    foreach (var item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
        //yield return item;
    }
}

// Now it will execute right away
nums.Where(x => x == 1).MyEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```