# Delete Multiple Items from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I want to delete multiple items in an ObservableCollection in C#.  My code is:

```
var item = (MoveDataModel)e.SelectedItem;
var answer = await DisplayAlert("Confirmation", "Are you sure you wish to delete " + item.value + "?", "Yes", "No");
        if (answer)
{
    var type = item.type;
    var value = item.value;

    foreach (var listItem in items)
    {
        if ((listItem.value == item.value) || (listItem.location == value && type == "Location"))
        {
            items.Remove(listItem);
            itemCount--;
        }
    }
}
```

The first iteration works fine.  However, it hangs on

```
foreach (var listItem in items)
```

on the second pass. I'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)

Answer (score 1):

you can't modify a collection while you're iterating over it.  Try something like this (I haven't checked the syntax, may need some cleanup)

```
var removeList = items.Where(x => x.value == value).Where(y => y.type = type).ToList();

foreach(var i in removeList) {
  items.Remove(i);
  itemCount--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your own counter, cycle backwards through the list so you wont have to readjust for indexes you removed.

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object> list = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object>();
private void RemoveStuff()
{
    var i = list.Count - 1;
    for (; i <= 0; i--)
    {
        // some checks here to make sure this is the time you really want to remove
        list.Remove(i);
    }

}
```