# System.InvalidOperationException weird error

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

Did anyone see this error?
I'm not able to understand what code statement did it, as it isn't available in the stacktrace.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>      at System.Reactive.PlatformServices.DefaultExceptionServices.Rethrow(Exception exception)
>      at System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver`1.OnError(Exception error)
>      at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ObserveOn`1.?.OnErrorPosted(Object error)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Application is wpf C#.net using Reactive. There are multiple locations where Reactive is being used, and the collections are locked for read/write operations using lock as a synchronization mechanism.

Note: In the entire code, I'm not iterating through the subscriber list or modifying it as well.

Comment: Sounds like a for-each loop is trying to modify the collection it's looping over.

Comment: We definitely need some more details, but judging from the message it would seem like your modifying an element of a collection you're currently iterating on (with foreach for example)
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute

Answer (score 0):

You have a `foreach` that invokes some changes on the enumerated collection. That is disallowed.

Alternatively another thread is changing the enumerated collection concurrently, which will also result in an exception.