# Dictionary methods Remove and Clear (.NET Core) modify the collection during enumeration. No exception thrown

Tags: c#, dictionary, for-loop, .net-core, enumeration

I am trying to implement a caching mechanism for [enumerating collections safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute/58618953#58618953), and I am checking if all modifications of the built-in collections are triggering an `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown by their respective enumerators. I noticed that in the .NET Core platform the [`Dictionary.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove) and [`Dictionary.Clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.clear) methods are not triggering this exception. Is this a bug or a feature?

Example with `Remove`:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(1, "Hello");
dictionary.Add(2, "World");
foreach (var entry in dictionary)
{
    var removed = dictionary.Remove(entry.Key);
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry} removed: {removed}");
}
Console.WriteLine($"Count: {dictionary.Count}");
```

Output:

> [1, Hello] removed: True
>   [2, World] removed: True
>   Count: 0

Example with `Clear`:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(1, "Hello");
dictionary.Add(2, "World");
foreach (var entry in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
    dictionary.Clear();
}
Console.WriteLine($"Count: {dictionary.Count}");
```

Output:

> [1, Hello]
>   Count: 0

The expected exception is:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

...as is thrown by the method `Add`, and by the same methods in .NET Framework.

.NET Core 3.0.0, C# 8, VS 2019 16.3.1, Windows 10

Comment: Confirmed: .Net full framework demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8vONOw; .Net core fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/es6STm.  Even weirder, .Net core throws for `SortedDictionary<int, string>()` as shown here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bssrG7.  You might report an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be an intentional difference between .Net full framework and .Net core for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

The divergence occurred in [Pull #18854: Remove version increment from Dictionary.Remove overloads](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/18854):

> Removes the version increment from Remove operations
>
> This addresses the coreclr side of the api change [Add Dictionary.Remove(predicate)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29979) with the intention of allowing removal of items from the dictionary while enumerating per direction from @jkotas . All collections tests and modified and new tests added in the related corefx PR.

There appears to be an open documentation issue:

[Issue #42123: Clarify Dictionary behavior/guarantees around mutation during enumeration](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42123#issuecomment-546482254):

> > Is it correct to say that the current implementation of Dictionary supports non-concurrent mutation during iteration?
>
> Only removal. This was enabled as a feature in [dotnet/coreclr#18854](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/18854).
>
> > is this something that can be depended on going forward
>
> Yes.
>
> We should ensure the docs are updated to reflect this.

You might want to add a vote to the open doc issue requesting clarification as the [.Net core 3.0 documentation for `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.getenumerator?view=netcore-3.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_GetEnumerator) is now **obsolete**:

> If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or **deleting** elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and the next call to `MoveNext` or `IEnumerator.Reset` throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

Strangely enough, the enumerator for [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netcore-3.0) *does* throw when the dictionary is modified during enumeration.

Demos:

- .Net framework `Remove()`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8vONOw (throws).
- .Net core `Remove()`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/es6STm (does not throw).
- .Net core `Add()`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6q7Lvx (throws).
- .Net core `Remove()` from `SortedDictionary<int, string>`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bssrG7 (throws).

Comment: bug report in here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42212

Comment: @dev-masih Checking `_version` appears to have been intentionally removed.  See [Allow Dictionary<K,V>.Remove during enumeration](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29979#issuecomment-399806076).

Comment: @BACON - yeah, I just found the pull request and updated my answer while you commented.

Comment: Another oddity: The [`Dictionary.TrimExcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trimexcess) method, available only on .NET Core, **does** causes the "Collection was modified" exception, without actually modifying the `Dictionary`!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - likely because *in practice* removing an entry from a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` doesn't break an ongoing iteration (since the active entries are in something like a linked list), but trimming the excess does because it rehashes everything.  BTW my answer isn't an endorsement of the change, I'm just reporting about it.

Comment: Yeap, this makes sense. So the "Collection was modified" refers to the internal data structure of the class, not to the externally visible data.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify when the change was made available and via which methods...

Microsoft's docs on the Dictionary's [.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=netcore-3.1) and [.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.clear?view=netcore-3.1) have been updated:

> .NET Core 3.0+ only: this mutating method may be safely called without invalidating active enumerators on the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> instance. This does not imply thread safety.

.NET Core 3.0 came with C# 8.0. Since then, we have been able to modify a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> during enumeration (`foreach`) via [.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=netcore-3.1) and [.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.clear?view=netcore-3.1) only.