# Idiom for removing a JsonNode?

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I am trying to modify an in memory [JsonNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0) instance. Minimal reproducible code is simply ([.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nWACRX)):

```
        string jsonString =
            @"{
  ""Date"": ""2019-08-01T00:00:00"",
  ""Temperature"": 25,
  ""Summary"": ""Hot"",
  ""DatesAvailable"": [
    ""2019-08-01T00:00:00"",
    ""2019-08-02T00:00:00""
  ],
  ""TemperatureRanges"": {
      ""Cold"": {
          ""High"": 20,
          ""Low"": -10
      },
      ""Hot"": {
          ""High"": 60,
          ""Low"": 20
      }
  }
}
";
        JsonNode jDataSet = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString)!;
        var dataSet = jDataSet.AsObject();
        foreach (var entry in dataSet)
        {
            if (entry.Key == "TemperatureRanges")
            {
                entry.Value.AsObject().Remove("Hot");
            }
            else if (entry.Key == "Date")
            {
                dataSet.Remove(entry.Key); // boom !
            }
        }
```

Obviously this is the wrong approach (as seen with other structure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)), how should I re-write the above code to handle removal of `JsonNode` in my case ?

Current code trigger:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyDictionary`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
   at Tests.UnitTest1.Test2() in C:\Users\malat\project\tests\Tests\UnitTest1.cs:line 43
```

Using:

```
> dotnet --version
6.0.408
```

Fundamentally my question is identical to this [one](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26314) but for JsonNode.

Comment: "Obviously this is the wrong approach" - you don't actually make that obvious in the question. Rather than posting pseudocode, please post a [mcve] including whatever happens that you don't want to happen.

Comment: Your code doesn't throw any exceptions for me... can you clarify which version of .NET you're using?

Comment: I *assumed* it was obvious because it is working for [dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62844729/136285).

Comment: Ah, I've figured it out. I hadn't spotted that your repro isn't actually a repro, because you've commented out the problematic line. I'd encourage you to uncomment that - I don't see the benefit in providing code that needs to be tweaked in order to reproduce the issue,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three options present themselves:

- Call `ToList()` to create a sequence to iterate over that won't be modified by calling `Remove`:

  ```
  foreach (var entry in dataSet.ToList())
  ```

  That's *somewhat* inefficient of course - whether that's a problem or not for you will depend on your app.
- Don't do the removal in the loop, but keep a list of keys you want to remove after iterating over `dataSet`.
- Don't bother keeping a list - just unconditionally call `dataSet.Remove("Date")` after the loop. (In your example at least, you know the key you want to remove - and `Remove` doesn't throw an exception if the key is missing anyway.)

Comment: Would it make sense to report `Allow JsonNode.Remove during enumeration` as an issue upstream ?

Comment: @malat: It wouldn't hurt to ask - but I'm not sure whether MS will want the additional complexity.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/87206