# Is there any way to edit the Values of a Dictionary during iteration?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, foreach, iterator

I want to change all the values that fulfill a certain criterium in a C# dictionary.

Simply editing the values like this

```
foreach (var kv in dictionary)
{
   kv.Value += 1;
}
```

does not work because the `KeyValuePair` of the `foreach` loop is read only.

However, editing the entries directly like this:

```
foreach (var kv in dictionary)
{
   dictionary[kv.Key] = kv.Value + 1;
}
```

also doesn't work, because it modifies the collection and breaks the iterator.

At this point, the only remaining solution I can think of is storing all keys of the dictionary in a list, and then using that to edit the values during a second loop, however, that seems like a pretty inelegant solution to me.

Is there any better alternative?

Comment: N.B. A [criterium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criterium) is a type of bicycle race. You want a *criterion*.

Comment: Have you considered using `ConcurrentDictionary` instead?

Comment: Non native speaker, sorry. The German word is "Kriterium".

Comment: In VB.NET you could have `x = x.Select(Of DictionaryEntry)(Function(de) New DictionaryEntry With {.Key = de.Key, .Value = de.Value + 1}).ToDictionary(Of String, Integer)(Function(k) k.Key.ToString(), Function(v) CInt(v.Value))` - the translation to C# eludes me.

Comment: Related: [Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an array (or a List with `.ToList()`) from the `.Keys` in the `foreach`, something like this:

```
foreach (string key in dictionary.Keys.ToArray())
{
    dictionary[key] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Or, `.ToList()`.  I would have thought that `dictionary.Keys` would fabricate a collection on the fly, but I guess it just implements an `IEnumerable<TKey>` using a `yield return` (or something along those lines).

Comment: Right, or `ToList()`, I included it in my answer, thank you @Flydog57 !

Comment: Right. I did think of that before, but I'm a dummy who forgot to include System.Linq, so I thought dictionaries don't have that option.

Comment: I tested it and yes, otherwise the exception about modifying the collection is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**ToDictionary**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1) to create new `Dictionary` and change the origin in the loop, like :

```
foreach (var kv in dictionary.ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,v=>v.Value))
{
   dictionary[kv.Key] = kv.Value + 1;
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: I'm a big dummy. I did think of that, but it didn't seem to work. The real problem was that I forgot to include System.Linq for some reason.