# Umbraco V7 deleting properties via content type service

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

quick Umbraco V7 question. I'm trying to programmatically remove a load of Vorto properties from a V7 site prior to upgrading, however I keep hitting `'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'` error when running the following code:

```
var contentTypes = _contentTypeService.GetAllContentTypes();
        foreach (var cts in contentTypes.Where(x => x.Id != 10546))
        {

            var vortoPropsToDelete = cts.PropertyTypes.Where(x => x.PropertyEditorAlias == "Our.Umbraco.Vorto");

            foreach (var vortoProp in vortoPropsToDelete)
            {
                cts.RemovePropertyType(vortoProp.Alias);
            }
            _contentTypeService.Save(cts);
        }
```

I can't work out were I'm going wrong...

Comment: Please remember to upvote the answers if they help you or approve them if they are the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco v7's [GetAllContentTypes](https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v7/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentTypeService.html) method returns a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Guid>` type and you are trying to update your GetAllContentTypes collection before you are finished iterating, hence you see this error.

Try to convert your [collection to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604843/1587012), update your code for this and that should work.