# What Is Going Wrong In My Collision Response?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a collision response system based on a collide and slide algorithm.

Only, I've been getting an error.

This is the code with the error:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class CollisionRepsonse
{ 
    public float RemainingVelocity;
    public RaycastHit CollisonHit;
    public Vector3 CollisionHitLocation;
    public Vector3 OutputForce;
}

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 CurrentInputDir;
    public float BaseVelocity = 5f;

    [SerializeField] List<CollisionRepsonse> CollisionHits;

    RaycastHit InitialCollisonHit;
    bool FirstCollisionHit;

    public int i = 0;

    void Update()
    { 
        if(Physics.CapsuleCast(transform.position, transform.position, 0.5f, CurrentInputDir, out InitialCollisonHit, BaseVelocity))
        { 
            if (CollisionHits.Count == 0f)
            { 
                FirstCollisionHit = true;
            }

            if (FirstCollisionHit)
            { 
                CollisionHits.Add(new CollisionRepsonse{}); 
                FirstCollisionHit = false;
            }

            if (CollisionHits.Count != 0f) 
            {
                CollisionResponseFunction();    
            }

            void CollisionResponseFunction()
            { 
                foreach(CollisionRepsonse CollisionRepsonse in CollisionHits)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    { 
                        CollisionHits[i].CollisionHitLocation = InitialCollisonHit.point;
                        CollisionHits[i].RemainingVelocity = BaseVelocity - Vector3.Distance(transform.position, CollisionHits[i].CollisionHitLocation);
                        CollisionHits[i].OutputForce = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(CurrentInputDir, InitialCollisonHit.normal);                         
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        //CollisionHits[i].CollisionHitLocation = CollisionHits[i - 1].CollisonHit.point;
                        //CollisionHits[i].RemainingVelocity = CollisionHits[i - 1].RemainingVelocity - Vector3.Distance(CollisionHits[i - 1].CollisionHitLocation, CollisionHits[i].CollisionHitLocation);
                        //CollisionHits[i].OutputForce = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(CollisionHits[i - 1].OutputForce, CollisionHits[i - 1].CollisonHit.normal);  
                    }

                    if (CollisionHits[i].RemainingVelocity > 0f) 
                    { 
                        CollisionHits.Add(new CollisionRepsonse{});    
                        i++;
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNextRare () (at <75633565436c42f0a6426b33f0132ade>:0)   System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext () (at <75633565436c42f0a6426b33f0132ade>:0)
> NewBehaviourScript.g__CollisionResponseFunction|6_0 () (at Assets/Scripts/NewBehaviourScript.cs:46)
> NewBehaviourScript.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/NewBehaviourScript.cs:41)

But once I change the code to this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class CollisionRepsonse
{ 
    public float RemainingVelocity;
    public RaycastHit CollisonHit;
    public Vector3 CollisionHitLocation;
    public Vector3 OutputForce;
}

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 CurrentInputDir;
    public float BaseVelocity = 5f;

    [SerializeField] 
    List<CollisionRepsonse> CollisionHits;

    RaycastHit InitialCollisonHit;
    bool FirstCollisionHit;

    public int i = 0;

    void Update()
    { 
        if (Physics.CapsuleCast(transform.position, transform.position, 0.5f, CurrentInputDir, out InitialCollisonHit, BaseVelocity))
        { 
            if (CollisionHits.Count == 0f)
            { 
                FirstCollisionHit = true;
            }

            if (FirstCollisionHit)
            { 
                CollisionHits.Add(new CollisionRepsonse{}); 
                FirstCollisionHit = false;
            }

            if (CollisionHits.Count != 0f) 
            {
                CollisionResponseFunction();    
            }

            void CollisionResponseFunction()
            { 
                foreach(CollisionRepsonse CollisionRepsonse in CollisionHits)
                {
                    if (CollisionHits[i].RemainingVelocity > 0f) 
                    { 
                        CollisionHits.Add(new CollisionRepsonse{});    
                        i++;
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it's fine...

So once I add these lines of code:

```
if (i == 0)
{ 
    CollisionHits[i].CollisionHitLocation = InitialCollisonHit.point;
    CollisionHits[i].RemainingVelocity = BaseVelocity - Vector3.Distance(transform.position, CollisionHits[i].CollisionHitLocation);
    CollisionHits[i].OutputForce = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(CurrentInputDir, InitialCollisonHit.normal);                         
}
```

It throws an error on the `foreach` loop, saying the collection was modified. I'm sure the value in the class is modified, but that's the point, I would store data in there, but it has nothing to do with the counter in the foreach loop anyway - just with the values in it.

I make sure I increase the integer and the listcount together to avoid this problem, and I'm making sure to calculate back not forward.

I tried everything, but I can't find the issue. I expected it to work fine since I can't find any error in my calculations...

But as I remove the above mentioned part of the code (which shouldn't interfere with the `foreach` loop), it seems to work.

Comment: You cannot modify a collection while you are iterating it using foreach.  `CollisionHits.Add(new CollisionRepsonse{});` is the culprit.  The second one is likely not erroring because the condition is not met, since you are not altering the RemainingVelocity anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection that is being iterated using foreach.
In both examples of code, you are attempting to add items to the collection that you are iterating over.

```
CollisionHits.Add(new CollisionRepsonse{});
```

The reason the second iteration of code works is because of the condition you have for adding new entries:

```
if (CollisionHits[i].RemainingVelocity > 0f)
```

This indicates the instance(s) have a RemainingVelocity less than or equal to zero.

To resolve the issue, use a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < CollisionHits.Count; i++)
{
    if (CollisionHits[i].RemainingVelocity > 0)
    {
        CollisionHits.Add(new CollisionHit());
        i++;
    }
}
```

I suggest reading the `Remarks` section in the [IEnumerable.GetEnumerator documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=net-8.0)

Comment: yeah thanks, ive been trying to avoid a for loop, but seems like there is no other way since c# is then just being stupid.

Comment: Not sure what exactly this is supposed to do .. but the for loop is still very error prone and a potential infinite loop .. (at least until OP uncomments the calculation that reduces the remaining force ...

Comment: Why should one of the initial elements even have a remaining force ... wouldn't it be enough to only check the very last one and if it has for e left add a new ones until the last (now a new last) doesn't fulfill this condition anymore?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute). If i'm not wrong, `foreach` gets confused if the collection is changed as you already showed. You can try `ToList()` in your code as `foreach(CollisionRepsonse CollisionRepsonse in CollisionHits.toList())`. I didn't tried this but might solve your issue.

I guess you can also just go with a `for` loop. For loop doesn't mind changing things in the middle of the loop.

Comment: jeez, thats kinda stupid ngl... i mean, im just adding one to the collection and applying it to the new one, it shouldnt be that hard to not get confused... but anyway thanks... im gonna try it.

Comment: umm it seems like it doesnt contain a defention .toList()